# Unable to open XMAL file in designer view with Blend for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: github, visual-studio-2017, blend

I'm trying to launch some XMAL files so I can add modifications to them through Blends' designer view, but when I try to open them I get an error saying they can't be opened.

The program files are being shared through Git Hub's plugin function so that updates can be accessed easier, and pushed and pulled on the fly.
I've got everything setup correctly from what it seems, but all I can see right now is the code, and I'm unable to see the graphics of any of the screens.

Is there something I'm missing, or something not set correctly?

[image: Example of error here]

Answer (score 0):

As shown [in this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/475344/the-xaml-designer-doesnt-show-when-developing-a-uw.html), check the following points:

- right click the Solution Explorer on the .XAML file and selecting Open With, to seee the option with the (Default).
  For example: "Automatic Editor Selector (XML) (Default)"
- Look for any XAML option in `Tools | Options`, like "XAML Designer".
  See if "Enable XAML Designer (requires restart of Visual Studio)" is already selected.
- check that no other modules [like Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation/?pivots=windows) is installed, since this error message is [documented for Xamarin.Forms XAML files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms-xaml-designer).

Comment: I checked the "Enable XAML Designer" option, and it is check. I also checked for any other mods that could be interfering, and I don't see anything that gives any red flag.Only thing I have extra installed out side any extra Visual Studio editions are the Git Hub plugin and Visual Assist. I've also tried this on two different machines and I get the same issue.

Comment: I checked my other PC, and it turns out that Xamarin was installed there, but even after uninstalling it there was no change, and I'm unable to open the files in designer.